# def function not running correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator, function

Please don't be too mean I have only started to use Python and wanted to try and complete a calculator that can use brackets and BIDMAS. I am currently at the stage of starting the part about brackets but when I run my program it will not run my def functions properly.

```
import time
import os
import random
import sys

print("=======================")
print("Use ^ for the power of")
print("Use + for adding")
print("Use - for subtracting")
print("Use * for multiplying")
print("Use / for dividing")
print("Use % for a percentage")
print("DON'T USE SPACES!")
print("=======================\n\n")

uilist = ""
uilength = ""
user_input = ""

def to_the_power_of(a):
    postion_n1 = a.index("^")
    postion_n2 = postion_n1 + 1
    n1 = int(a[:postion_n1])
    n2 = int(a[postion_n2:])
    total = n1**n2
    sign = "^"

def subtracting(a):
    postion_n1 = a.index("-")
    postion_n2 = postion_n1 + 1
    n1 = int(a[:postion_n1])
    n2 = int(a[postion_n2:])
    total = n1-n2
    sign = "-"

def adding(a):
    postion_n1 = a.index("+")
    postion_n2 = postion_n1 + 1
    n1 = int(a[:postion_n1])
    n2 = int(a[postion_n2:])
    total = n1+n2
    sign = "+"

def multiplying(a):
    postion_n1 = a.index("*")
    postion_n2 = postion_n1 + 1
    n1 = int(a[:postion_n1])
    n2 = int(a[postion_n2:])
    total = n1*n2
    sign = "x"

def dividing(a):
    postion_n1 = a.index("/")
    postion_n2 = postion_n1 + 1
    n1 = int(a[:postion_n1])
    n2 = int(a[postion_n2:])
    total = n1/n2
    sign = "/"

def percentage(a):
    postion_n1 = a.index("%")
    postion_n2 = postion_n1 + 1
    n1 = int(a[:postion_n1])
    n2 = int(a[postion_n2:])
    total = (n1*n2)/100
    sign = "%"

def calculate(ab):
    uilength = len(ab)
    uilist = list(ab)
    if "^" in uilist:
        to_the_power_of(answer_1)

    elif "+" in uilist:
        adding(answer_1)

    elif "-" in uilist:
        subtracting(answer_1)

    elif "*" in uilist:
        multiplying(answer_1)

    elif "/" in uilist:
        dividing(answer_1)

    elif "%" in uilist:
        percentage(answer_1)

    else:
        print("Please eneter a valid calculation!")

while True:
    user_input = input("Write your calculation: ")


    answer_1 = user_input
    calculate(user_input)

    print(user_input,"=",total)

    exit_cal = input("Would you like to exit or make a now calculation?").lower()
    exit_list = ["exit","quit","leave","404"]
    if exit_cal in exit_list:
        sys.exit()
```

This is the error I get

```
=======================
Use ^ for the power of
Use + for adding
Use - for subtracting
Use * for multiplying
Use / for dividing
Use % for a percentage
DON'T USE SPACES!
=======================


Write your calculation: 12*4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Python Scripts\Calculator.py", line 99, in <module>
    print(user_input,"=",total)
NameError: name 'total' is not defined
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code snippet is far too broad and contains a lot of code not relevant to your question. In order to improve your chances for getting an answer, you may want to limit your sample code to bare minimum essential for asked question. To help you with that, you may want to get familiar with [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you mean `total = calculate(user_input)` ?

Comment: Your not defining total the def function is working just fine

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do such a thing is to define functions that return values. Notice the **return** statement at the end:

```
def subtracting(a):
  postion_n1 = a.index("-")
  postion_n2 = postion_n1 + 1
  n1 = int(a[:postion_n1])
  n2 = int(a[postion_n2:])
  return n1-n2
```

Then, you can print the result like so:

```
total = subtracting(ab)
print(user_input,"=",total)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code and added comments everywhere I made changes. If the same changes were made I just add a **...**.

```
import time
import os
import random
import sys

print("=======================")
print("Use ^ for the power of")
print("Use + for adding")
print("Use - for subtracting")
print("Use * for multiplying")
print("Use / for dividing")
print("Use % for a percentage")
print("DON'T USE SPACES!")
print("=======================\n\n")

uilist = ""
uilength = ""
user_input = ""

def to_the_power_of(a):
    postion_n1 = a.index("^")
    postion_n2 = postion_n1 + 1
    n1 = int(a[:postion_n1])
    n2 = int(a[postion_n2:])
    total = n1**n2
    sign = "^"
    return total #Remember if you want your function to produce a result other than None, you must use keyword return because variables inside functions exist only in functions until returned and assigned a variable in another scope.

def subtracting(a):
    postion_n1 = a.index("-")
    postion_n2 = postion_n1 + 1
    n1 = int(a[:postion_n1])
    n2 = int(a[postion_n2:])
    total = n1-n2
    sign = "-"
    return total #...

def adding(a):
    postion_n1 = a.index("+")
    postion_n2 = postion_n1 + 1
    n1 = int(a[:postion_n1])
    n2 = int(a[postion_n2:])
    total = n1+n2
    sign = "+"
    return total #...

def multiplying(a):
    postion_n1 = a.index("*")
    postion_n2 = postion_n1 + 1
    n1 = int(a[:postion_n1])
    n2 = int(a[postion_n2:])
    total = n1*n2
    sign = "x"
    return total #...

def dividing(a):
    postion_n1 = a.index("/")
    postion_n2 = postion_n1 + 1
    n1 = int(a[:postion_n1])
    n2 = int(a[postion_n2:])
    total = n1/n2
    sign = "/"
    return total #...

def percentage(a):
    postion_n1 = a.index("%")
    postion_n2 = postion_n1 + 1
    n1 = int(a[:postion_n1])
    n2 = int(a[postion_n2:])
    total = (n1*n2)/100
    sign = "%"
    return total #...

def calculate(ab):
    uilength = len(ab)
    uilist = list(ab)
    if "^" in uilist:
        answer = to_the_power_of(question) #You did the same mistake here. But this is part 2 of the mistake. You need a variable to return from calculate.

    elif "+" in uilist:
        answer = adding(question) #...

    elif "-" in uilist:
        answer = subtracting(question) #...

    elif "*" in uilist:
        answer = multiplying(question) #...

    elif "/" in uilist:
        answer = dividing(question) #...

    elif "%" in uilist:
        answer = percentage(question) #...

    else:
        print("Please eneter a valid calculation!")

    return answer #This will allow calculate to return the result

while True:
    user_input = input("Write your calculation: ")

    question = user_input
    answer = calculate(user_input) #Assign a variable for the result being returned from calculate.

    print(user_input,"=",answer)

    exit_cal = input("Would you like to exit or make a now calculation?").lower()
    exit_list = ["exit","quit","leave","404"]
    if exit_cal in exit_list:
        sys.exit()
```

Great job, you might want to explore the concept of **classes**. That would make your program much more robust.

Here were your problems:

1. Your mathematic functions (adding, subtracting, multiplying etc.) did not return any values. As a result, they were actually doing calculations but not returning the result. You saved the result to the value **total** which you should have returned using **return total**. This issue was present in all functions involving calculations and total.
2. Your **calculate** function did not return a result to your while loop to display as a result. So whether you assign **calculate(user_input)** to a variable or not, the result will be **None**. Fix this by placing a variable assignment in each of your **if** and **elif** statements in order for each body to initialize a variable **answer**.
3. Lastly remember to **return answer** and give it a local variable name in your **while True** loop. I gave it the name answer. This is not the same answer as in the function **calculate**. It is now a new global variable assigned the value of **answer** from the **calculate** function.

You had some repetitive code in there as well. You could have written a function for finding the arguments.

```
def findArguments(question,operator):
    postion_n1 = question.index(operator)
    postion_n2 = postion_n1 + 1
    n1 = int(question[:postion_n1])
    n2 = int(question[postion_n2:])
    return (n1,n2) #This is a tuple of the 2 integers.
```

Example usage:

```
def dividing(a):
    arguments = findArguments(a,"/")
    total = arguments[0]/arguments[1]
    return total
```